# Почему внутренний div с margin: auto не выравнивается по вертикали?

Tags: html, css, выравнивание, margin

В родительского div'a с классом контейнер известна ширина и высота, но дочерний div с классом контент не хочет выравниваться вертикально с помощью margin: auto. В чем причина? [image: код]

Comment: margin не умеет выравнивать по вертикали по природе своей, лучше переходите на flexbox

Answer (score 0):

### Можно так

```
.container {
    line-height: 600px;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: gainsboro;
}

.content {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

### А можно вот так

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: gainsboro;
}

.content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid;
}
```

Comment: У меня первый способ работает, только если по соседству с блоком content есть какой-то текст. А если внимательно измерить его линейкой, то окажется, что блок выровнялся на 2 пикселя ниже центра

Comment: Второй способ не работает?